# MVC (модель)

Tags: mvc, php

Появился вопрос -  где хранить данные полученные моделью?
В самой модели?
Передавать прямо в вид через set(get()) в контроллере?
Или есть другие варианты?

В первом случае проблема стоит - как передать в вид? вызовом из вида функции? или указателем на данные в модели?

Второй вариант: а не накладно ли для памяти? По идее данные будут аж в 3х местах(если правильно считаю).

Быть может я не правильно понимаю MVC?

UPD: очередной раз убеждаюсь в неумении излагать свои мысли.

Model

```
class some_model
{
public $data;

public function get_something();
}
```

Controller

```
class some_controller
{
$tmp = $this->model->get_something();

$this->view->set_something($tmp);
}
```

Как логичнее поступить?
Передавать копию того, что возвращает модель в вид?
Или же писать в функции get все в data и возвращать указатель на data?

Так же я где-то видел, что есть вариант что сам вид запрашивает данные от модели по средствам get. Однако я не понимаю как это реализовать и в чем преимущества варианта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе ваш код верен и не нужно забивать себе голову ерундой где и как :) 
Модель mvc и была разработана для того, что-бы полностью отделить файлы видов от всего остального кода, а так же вынести все запросы и проверки в файлы моделей! Например если я вас правильно понял можно было просто написать:

```
class some_model
{
public $data;

public function get_something(){
$data=$this->db->query->get('something');
$this->view->set_something($data);              // неправильный подход
};

}
```

Но  если в этом методе мы получаем данные которые например нам будут нужны в следующем контроллере, и при попытке их получить мы наткнемся на грабли. 
Контроллеры для того и придуманы, что они служат связующим звеном между клиентом и моделями. Поэтому вывод нужно делать только в контроллере, а насчет того, что данные будут храниться в трех местах - это не правильное мнение, все хранится в одном месте, ведь мы по ходу необходимости все подгружаем именно в контроллер, а потом это все передаем в вид!

Comment: Вы меня не поняли я имел ввиду вызов из вида запроса данных из модели. К тому же я не считаю что мой вопрос - экономия на спичках.
При большом количестве запросов расход памяти будет сказываться.

Answer (score 4):

Не силен в PHP, но попробую ответить, ибо MVC он везде MVC. На самом деле надо понимать что есть что, попробую расписать в кратце.

**M (model)** - это обработанные и подготовленные данные запрошенные пользователем, а так же логика взаимодействия с пользователем. Работает на клиентской стороне.
**V (view)** - это отображение данных, никакой логики и никакого хранения данных. Оно просто знает как отобразить до что ему дает model и передает сигналы той же самой model'и обеспечивая взаимодействие с пользователем.
**C (controller)** - а вот тут самое интересное, он тоже не хранит данные. Его задача принимать запросы от model'и и получив из базы отдать их model'и. Иногда может позволить себе немного обработать эти данные. Работает на серверной стороне.

из всего сказанного выше следует что данные хранятся в базе и model'и пока они нужны для отображения. И более того, если не использовать MVC они так же будут храниться в двух местах пока нужны для отображения. Надеюсь я понятно и в тему все написал.

Comment: Вы правильно. Ставлю +. =) Только момент на счёт клиентской стороны в вебе спорный, клиентский - JavaScript, который может быть отключён, так что данные приходится обрабатывать через сервер и так и так, для подстраховки.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно понимаете MVC от части. Данные выводятся только в виде(view). Model - характеризует конкретную сущность и работает с ней. Controller нужен для управления моделями и видами и всем тем, что вы туда припишите не нарушая модели MVC, он главный компоновщик для определённой страницы.

Пример модели: пользователь (user_mdl).

Это модель может содержать разного рода методы: получение имени пользователя, получение его постов / друзей, его контактов и т.д Модель User - это сущность, и через методы этой модели мы работаем с этой сущностью, с теми св-вами, которые для неё характерны, обрабатывем их, шлифуем.

Данные полученные моделью в передаются в вид в виде какого-либо ассива или стрктуры данных, не знаю что за методы get / set всё зависит от вашей реализаци, но для того чтобы передать в вид данные нужно иметь подготовленную структуру библиотек, так как зачастую термин "передать в вид" означает: передать в функцию view два аргумента: путь к файлу с видом и набор данных в массиве data.

Это не сильно накладно по ресурсам, но благодаря такой структуре разработчики выезжают на быстроте реализации проекта, они делают его качественнее, структурированнее, что ведёт к низкому риску возникновения ошибок и непоняток.

А данные хранятся либо в файлах / либо в БД, то бишь в одном месте. А с помощью модели мы запрашиваем эти данные в контроллере, где после массив данных передаётся в вид.
Контроллер объединяет / компонует результат работы моделей и видов.